# how to return value of selected id in database php

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I insert in the database a csv file. how will i return the id and use it to insert in another table. it always displays array to string conversion errror. is there something wrong with "return"

here is my controller

```
public function uploadThree(){
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false)
    {
        $appname = $fileop[0];
        $servname = $fileop[1];
        $ciname = $fileop[2];
        $servid = $this->some_model->insertBulkServ($servname); //i tried to get the value here then insert below
        $appid = $this->some_model->insertBulkSingleApp($appname);//i tried to get the value here then insert below
        $this->some_model->insertBulkCI($ciname);
        $this->some_model->ASMAP($appid,$servid);
    }

    if($success == TRUE)
        redirect(base_url().'some_controller/uploadPage');
}
```

MODEL

```
public function insertBulkServ($service) {
/* Inserts csv file for a service */
    $service = $this->db->escape_str($service);

    $queryStr = "Select service from appwarehouse.service where service = '$service' and VISIBILITY = 'VISIBLE'";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){

        $queryStr = "SELECT id FROM appwarehouse.service WHERE service='$service' AND visibility = 'VISIBLE';";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        $row = $query->result();
        return $row;
        //in here how do i get the ID how do i return it
    }else{
        $queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.service(service) VALUES ('$service');";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);

        $queryStr = "SELECT id FROM appwarehouse.service WHERE service='$service' AND visibility = 'VISIBLE';";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        $row = $query->result();
        return $row;
    } 
}



public function insertBulkSingleApp($app_name) {
    /* Inserts csv file for an application       */
    $app_name = $this->db->escape_str($app_name);

    $queryStr = "Select * from appwarehouse.application_table where app_name = '$app_name' and VISIBILITY = 'VISIBLE'";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $queryStr = "SELECT id FROM appwarehouse.application_table WHERE app_name='$app_name' AND visibility = 'VISIBLE';";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        $row = $query->result();
        return $row;
    }
    else{
        $queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.application_table(app_name) 
                    VALUES ('$app_name');";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        $queryStr = "SELECT id FROM appwarehouse.application_table WHERE app_name='$app_name' AND visibility = 'VISIBLE';";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        $row = $query->result();
        return $row;
    } 
}



public function ASMAP($appid,$servid) {

    $appid = $this->db->escape_str($appid);
    $servid = $this->db->escape_str($servid);

    $queryStr = "Select * from appwarehouse.app_service where app_id = '$appid' AND serv_id = '$servid' and VISIBILITY = 'VISIBLE'";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        $queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.app_service(app_id,serv_id) 
                    VALUES ('$appid','$servid');";
        $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

## $this->db->insert_id()

*The insert ID number when performing database inserts.*

More Info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it it is very simple
After the query insert

```
$queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.service(service) VALUES ('$service');";
```

Instead of select use this

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```

Or if you really need to return the object

```
$queryStr = "SELECT id FROM appwarehouse.application_table WHERE app_name='$app_name' AND visibility = 'VISIBLE';";
$query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
```

Return id instead of object

```
return $query->row()->id;
```

One more thing to note. insert_id is the last inserted id so you dont have to run select query to get id.

Also use `row()` to select single record. `result()` selects multiple records so you will get an array. see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

Comment: it says undefined $id in return $query->result()->id;

Comment: sorry it should be `row()` instead of `result()`

Comment: what if i want to insert the same entry with different combinations

Comment: there is something wrong with return $query->row()->id; when i insert the same value with different combinations

Comment: Well in `insertBulkServ` you insert only one record and return the id then you use that id to another combination in `insertBulkSingleApp` so that's fine you dont need to worry.

Comment: while you are in loop you need to assign `$servid`  in this array `$appname` to make relationship